# Checking for missing file in form post

Tags: html, forms, go

Summary: I want to know when a blank HTML file field is submitted, but my code only seems to capture those with file(s) attached. Is there any workaround?

I have a form that allows user to submit files with some metadata about them, something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>
      Paper abstract: 
      <input type="text" name="abstract" />
 </label>

 <label>
     <div class="item">Upload paper in PDF format only</div>
     <input type="file" name="file" />
 </label>

 <!-- the interface allows the html above to be duplicated and submit more papers, e.g., -->

 <label>
      Paper abstract: 
      <input type="text" name="abstract" />
 </label>

 <label>
     <div class="item">Upload paper in PDF format only</div>
     <input type="file" name="file" />
 </label>

<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

The server code handles the post something like this:

```
func Upload(r *http.Request){

    papers := len(r.Form["abstract"])//Check how many papers the user is submitting

    r.ParseMultipartForm(config.MaxMemory)

    for i := 0; i < papers; i++{

      //Saves file and returns bytes -- implemented elsewhere
      //This line will fail unless every file field has an attachment.
      //I'd like to see blank file fields too.
      path, fileSize := uploadFile(r.MultipartForm.File["file"][i])

      paper := &Paper{//struct defined elsewhere
         Abstract: r.Form["abstract"][i]
         Path: path, 
         Size: size,
      }

      savePaper(paper) //implemented elsewhere

    }
}
```

Thanks for any tips.